# Why does "greater than" comparison of numbers give unexpected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is an input field, like this,

```
 <input class="form-control" type="number" name="recieved_by_quantity" id="quantity" />
```

Dynamically, a value is assigned to the input tag, like this,

```
 document.getElementById('quantity').value = qu;    //var qu=11 lets say
```

Now, what i want is, if the user manually inputs a value greater than "qu", then the value would automatically change itself to "qu".

What i did for this is something like,

```
 document.getElementById('quantity').addEventListener("change", function() {
    var qc = this.value; 
    if(qc>qu) {
        this.value = qu;
    } 
});
```

The strange thing that is happening is if i input any value from 2 to infinity, it is changing all of them to 11. Only value it does not change are 0,1,10,100,1000,10000 and so on..
I am completely confused. Please help.

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/35nbL5qd/

Comment: What's the value of `qu`? Is it the number `11` or the string `"11"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parseInt

```
var qc = parseInt(this.value)
```

Comment: Explain why he should do this.

Comment: This shouldn't be needed if `qu` is a number.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati: Does this answer help you understand why?

Comment: i admit, qu was parsed dynamically, using, var qu = $(z).parent().siblings("#pendin").html();

Comment: yes, this helped me a lot. qu actually was a string and not a number

Comment: qu is a number but quantity input box is a string. you need to convert to number before comparing

Comment: @yogeshprajapati: Why does it matter that it's a string?

Comment: @Piyush.kapoor: If `qu` was a number, it would work. Do you understand the what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Its simple, use parseInt to get actual number value of your text-area.

You are getting string by default.

this.value is giving you '11'
parseInt(this.value) is giving you 11.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="recieved_by_quantity" id="quantity" />
</body>
<script>
var qu = 11;
 document.getElementById('quantity').value = qu;  
 document.getElementById('quantity').addEventListener("change", function() { 
    var qc = parseInt(this.value); 
    if(qc>qu) {
        this.value = qu;
    } 
});
</script>
</html>
```